# AUTOSAR clarification about the data type

Tags: automotive, can

I have seen the following typedef [image: Typedef]

the link of the document is[AUTOSAR CAN NM](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/4-3/AUTOSAR_SWS_CANNetworkManagement.pdf) 
[image: CANNm GlobalCfg]

He refers to the term container and mapped to the data type CanNm_ConfigType. what does the term container mean? [image: Datatype]

So the structure CanNm_ConfigType should contain the elements in the picture above? Am I correct? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

When you develop autosar software, you generally employ tools like EB Tresos etc as it is very tedious to develop every module keeping in mind all the Autosar requirements.
CanNm_ConfigType is in programming terms, a structure that contains all the values required by CanNm for proper functionality.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes. Your Understanding is Correct.**

`CanNm_ConfigType` is a structure that contains the `CanNm_GlobalConfig` parameters. This C Datatype is used to pass the configuration controls to the `CanNm_Init` function.

Autosar mentions the CanNm_GlobalConfig as a "Container" because it does not hold any value. It is holding the set of parameters under it.

This is useful for the Autosar Tool developers to parse the ARXML files directly. This term container can be synonymically used as a Package (XML,Java) or Dictionary (.Net).

Basically, The Autosar Containers just holds the parameter sets.